# Where can I find the magnifying glass UI for iOS 10?

Tags: iphone

Just looking for the UI for the magnifying glass feature in the recent iOS 10.

Comment: you mean the two finger stretch?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for ways to zoom the screen:

*Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Zoom* (second option from the top)

If you want to use the camera as a magnifying glass:

*Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Magnify* (third option from the top)